# Switch from Debian Jessie to LMDE

Tags: debian, testing, lmde

I don't like what GNOME applications, such as Gedit, came to be and how they look now in Debian Testing. These colorless and borderless windows with unfamiliar layout are totally unusable for me.

I know that LMDE uses Debian Testing as its base, but GNOME applications are still normal there. So can I switch to it?

Comment: So don't install GNOME. Install something else. What's the question here?

Comment: muru, before commenting on posts, please be sure to carefully read them. I don't install GNOME. I use GNOME applications, if you know, what it means.

Comment: And before posting questions, please make them concise and to the point. After reading the first para, I had no desire to read further.

Comment: Well, luckily you aren't obliged :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you only need change the repos at /etc/apt/sources.list

I did the opposite, change LMDE to Debian without troubles except in Cinnamon, no big deal and change to MATE. However, the next LMDE will be based on [Stable](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=201&t=173117), not on Testing.

Comment: I thought so too, I did it. But then I got into trouble. I made `apt-get upgrade` in order to downgrade all packages to versions in LMDE repos. But something went wrong: Python packages got broken, and Cinnamon stopped to load. After all I gave up and installed Linux Mint. :)